# LOOCV, Confusion Matrix and KNN in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, knn

I am trying to write my own function of KNN. I do not use the built function in R, because I want to use different distances (norms, such as L_0.1) instead of Euclidean distance. In addition, I would like to use LOOCV to separate the dataset. Previously, I separated my data as in below code and everything goes well.But I need to use LOOCV.

```
wdbc<- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data",sep=",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
     wdbc<-wdbc[-1]
     normalize <- function(x) {
       return ((x-min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))}
     wdbc_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(wdbc[2:31], normalize))
     wdbc_train<-wdbc_n[1:568,]
     wdbc_test<-wdbc_n[569:569,]
```

I have also try to write the LOOCV code.

```
LOOOCV_training=list()
for(i in 1:nrow(wdbc_n)){
  LOOOCV_training[[i]]=wdbc_n[-i,]}
View(LOOOCV_training)

LOOOCV_testing=list()
for(i in 1:nrow(wdbc_n)){
  LOOOCV_testing[[i]]=wdbc_n[i,]}
```

My questions

How to put LOOCV separation instead of the separation I did before?
In other words, I used some codes such as `Dist=matrix(0,nrow=nrow(wdbc_train),ncol=nrow(wdbc_test))` 
It was easy to deal with the first split I did before, but now I am not sure because of LOOCV, train the model on all training set except on one test set and repeat this process n times. The dimension of my data is 569 32, that means not easy to do the process one by one.

Also, how to calculate confusion matrix with LOOCV, since LOOCV repeated the process many times, which means I will have many confusion matrices!!

**EDIT**

To be more clear,suppose that I want to use LOOCV split instead in the following code (previous codes).

```
Dist=matrix(0,nrow=nrow(wdbc_train),ncol=nrow(wdbc_test))
Dist2=array(0,nrow(wdbc_test))
for (i in 1:nrow(wdbc_train)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(wdbc_test)){
    Dist[i,j]=norm(as.matrix(wdbc_train[i,]-wdbc_test[j,]),type="i")}}
```

Comment: The splitting looks fine, please provide the part of your code which actually fails.

Comment: @mhwh, I edited my question